# Which open-source comet/ reverse-ajax libraries will you recommend to be used with Tomcat 5.5? Why?

Tags: open-source, comet, tomcat5.5, reverse-ajax

I have seen continuations in Jetty 6.0 that addresses scaling for comet/reverse-ajax applications.

Are there any other libraries/frameworks to be used with Tomcat 5.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.dev.java.net/) is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would check out DWR(Direct Web Remoting).  It has fairly decent documentation and a respectable user base.

[DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[ItsNat Comet](http://www.innowhere.com:8080/itsnat/feashow_servlet?itsnat_doc_name=feashow.main&feature=feashow.core.listeners.cometNotifier.ex) works with Java 1.4 JVMs including Tomcat 5.5 with this JVM, of course upper versions of Java and servlet containers are supported.